# ANALOG story about Genetic engineering

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, genetics

OK, tricky one. I know the title, not the author.

Sometime in the last couple decades, ANALOG magazine ran a story called "Super Hero" about a robbery of a submarine sandwich shop (hence the pun title).

It takes place in a future where genetic engineering has given people an assortment of traits, which many of the possessors use for crime.  An unaltered person wins out against the robbers by using talents developed by training, not genetic manipulation.

I'd like to track this down, but I need the author name. Yes, I've tried Google; it fixates on the title and serves up DC and MCU references, nothing useful. The magazine website itself has no search facilities for stories last time I looked, and I cannot return to the fora there as password recovery requires the old password, which I lost with an HD crash. So, hive mind of Stack Exchange, can you assist please?

Comment: There was a story called ["The Super Hero Saves the World"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?278271) published in The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, June 2003, but that's the only short fiction containing ["Super Hero" in the title](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=super+hero&type=Fiction+Titles), published in a magazine, listed on ISFDb.

Comment: Originally mentioned in a comment at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94762/natural-born-woman-gets-revenge-on-gene-enhanced-people?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: [There is a description of The Super Hero Saves the World here](https://www.blackgate.com/2018/12/11/birthday-reviews-m-rickerts-the-super-hero-saves-the-world/). It doesn't look as if it is the right story.

Comment: I found an [index of ANALOG magazines](http://drvonbyte.blogspot.com/2018/09/analog-computing-magazine-full-index.html). but not the story or anything close. Many of the magazines are freely available on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=analog+magazine), but I didn't find the story by searching there either.

Comment: @Laurel I assume the magazine is Analog Science Fiction and Fact, rather than Analog Computing.

Comment: I've had a look at the Analog index here: https://www.analogsf.com/the-rivets/index/ but found nothing - does this mean the story was published prior to 2010?

Comment: I was thinking between 2003-2008 to be the most likely area, but thanks for confirming :)

Comment: FuzzyBoots, that was me again :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Super Gyro"  by Grey Rollins

Review from [Stranger than SF](https://strangerthansf.com/reviews/analog-2007-01JanuaryFebruary.html):

> Linus works in a gyro shop. When gunmen hold them up, a few customers
>   try and fail to use their genetically enhanced powers to overpower the
>   criminals. Linus, with no power, must outthink the gunmen and take
>   them down.

Comment: *face palm* I should have thought of that spelling...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I *did* think of that spelling when chatting about the "hero" pun, but that didn't loop back to the title!!  

Comment: Oh, heck! I didn't even think of all the alternate names! Thanks so much!